# ¿Como autoescalar mi aplicacion en diferentes resoluciones de pantalla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hice un programa con Windows forms en visual studio c#2017, y quiero poder agregarle que los formularios se ajusten automáticamente a la resolución de la pantalla, pero no lo he logrado.
En mi búsqueda me encontré con el siguiente código:

```
void AjustarResolución(Form form)
    {
        String ancho = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width.ToString();//Obtenemos el ancho de la pantalla
        String alto = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height.ToString();//Obtenemos el alto de la pantalla
        String tamaño = ancho + "x" + alto;//concatenamos para hacer un switch
        switch (tamaño)
        {
            case "800x600":
                cambiarResolucion(form, 110F, 110F);//Hacemos el ajuste con esta función
                break;
            case "1024x600":
                cambiarResolucion(form, 96F, 110F);
                break;
            default:
                cambiarResolucion(form, 96F, 110F);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void cambiarResolucion(Form formu, float ancho, float alto)
    {
        formu.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(ancho, alto);//Ajustamos la resolución
        formu.PerformAutoScale();//Escalo el control y los controles
    }
```

Pero no he logrado que funcione, cabe aclarar que a los formularios les quite la barra de titulo para poder hacer una barra personalizada.
Y si me pudieran ayudar para poder poner este código en una clase, para que todos los formularios los pueda referenciar a esa clase y no estra repitiendo este código con todos los formularios.

Comment: en winform estas complicado para esto que te propones, no soporta bien cambio de resolucion, quizas debas evaluar migrar a WPF

Answer (score 3):

Para que los controles escalen cuando amplias o disminuyes el form te debes basar en el uso del `Anchor` y `Dock`, son las unicas formas que soporta winform, sino deberias evaluar pasarte a `WPF`

[Dynamically Resizing Controls On Windows Forms - Using Anchor Property](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/dynamically-resizing-controls-on-windows-forms-using-ancho/)

[Configuring Your Form for Resizing](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102148&seqNum=5)

en estos articulo oficiales sobre `Windows Forms` explica como aplicar estas propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Ajustar el tamaño y la escala de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/adjusting-the-size-and-scale-of-windows-forms)

[Ajuste automático de escala en Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms)

Comment: "son las unicas formas que soporta winform", eso no es del todo cierto, tienes por ejemplo el control TableLayoutPanel, que permite organizar controles en columnas/renglones, o el control FlowLayoutPanel.